# ssh - Bad configuration option: KeyAlgorithms

Tags: git, ssh, gerrit

I've started a gerrit server. When I try to ssh to it I get:

```
Unable to negotiate with 127.0.0.1 port 29418: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

As this is deprecated it needs to be manually enabled (http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html):

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 username@localhost -p 29418
```

This works fine. Now I want to `git clone`, but need to pass the `KexAlgorithms` option to ssh via git. One solution is to [add the option to `~/.ssh/config`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7772571/1888983). This is what I added:

```
Host localhost
    KeyAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

The problem is I get the following error:

```
/home/username/.ssh/config: line 6: Bad configuration option: keyalgorithms
```

There's a `HostKeyAlgorithms` option that works there but that complains `Bad key types '+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'`. How should I configure `git`/`ssh` to connect to gerrit?

Comment: The title says it's complaining about "KexAlgorithms". In the post you say you added "HostKeyAlgorithms", and that it's complaining about "keyalgorithms". Maybe you could clarify what is on line 6 of your config file, and what it's actually complaining about.

Comment: @Kenster thanks, that's the issue and I still didn't see it even after messing with it for half an hour. Have updated to make it consistent. Not sure this post is at all constructive now considering it's purely a typo issue. Happy to delete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put there different option in the configuration, than on the command line. It should be

```
Host localhost
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

`KexAlgorithms` are not the `HostKeyAlgorithms`. They are completely different options with different values serving for different purposes.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing! I read my post again when you replied and was at first shocked that I'd written `Kex` instead of `Key`, but it turns out it should actually be `KexAlgorithms`.

Comment: I get the same error for the code in your answer.

Comment: @TomášZato Can you clarify?