# Git clone private repo inside a docker container

Tags: linux, git, docker, ssh, rsa

I have a docker container, and inside this docker container I have a shell script which performs a git clone from a private repo. The script is as follows:

```
eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null
# add the ssh key
ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa

kill $SSH_AGENT_PID

git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git
```

but when docker is running it gives an error

```
Cloning into 'repo'...
Host key verification failed.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

When I test on my local machine, I can clone the repo without a failure, so I know there is nothing wrong with my ssh keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you have a setup like this on your local machine you have an access to the terminal for SSH adding the key to the `known_hosts` asking

```
The authenticity of host 'server-name (***)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is XXXXXXX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

and you can basically interact, and type `yes` and ssh-agent add the connection to the `known_hosts` for you. However, in this case the things happen inside a docker container, and you basically cannot interect with this prompt. The solution for this is to add `StrictHostKeyChecking no` flag to ssh config, there are several ways to do it for `git` command, and you can check them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772190/passing-ssh-options-to-git-clone).

So basically, the following is the elegant way to solve this, just make `.ssh/config` file and add the ssh options we want.

```
eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null
# add the ssh key
ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa

kill $SSH_AGENT_PID

echo "Host bitbucket.org" > /root/.ssh/config
echo "User git" >> /root/.ssh/config
echo "IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /root/.ssh/config
echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /root/.ssh/config

git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/project/repo.git
```

`StrictHostKeyChecking no` option just discards the prompt and directly adds the connection to the `known_hosts`, and basically afterwards can `git clone`.

Comment: Turning off host checking leaves you vulnerable to a person-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: Well, I'd love to hear better alternatives. Actually this is my work around, but I am not sure if it's a best practice though for me this container is in AWS ECR an its permission policy is strict, so should be okay, but when I try locally it may be open to vulnerabilities.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk any suggestions ?

Comment: no, other than verify the keys ahead of time and place them in known_hosts. Host keys should change very infrequently. Many users just click "Yes" to the prompt without checking, so setting StrictHostKeyChecking to no doesn't make things any worse. My comment is just to document a security fact.