# How to exclude SSH-agents in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh-keygen

I created an agent in Powershell to manage an SSH key created directly in Git, but when deleting the key it still requests permission to be able to clone the repository even if the key has been deleted and I can no longer clone unless I have the key back which led me to believe that the agent created in Powershell is preventing it from cloning even without a key, how do I delete this agent in Powershell?

I used this command as admin in Powershell:

```
get-service -name ssh-agent | set-service -startuptype manual
```

```
start-service ssh-agent
```

```
ssh-add ***``key directory``***
```

Procurei sobre como apagar mais não achei nada só como encerrar o Powershell mas bom encerrar ele não retira o problema de forma definitiva.

Comment: It prompts you when you delete the existing keys? Or does it prompt you when you subsequently do `git clone ...`?

Comment: I can delete the pub and priv key and get the error after using Git clone, this one:


This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Comment: The key being referenced in the error is not yours, it's the public key advertised by github's sshd. You can change the ssh command line used by git to disable strict host verification https://stackoverflow.com/a/56948182/712649

Comment: I created the keys and performed the **Git clone** in **Gitbash**, I used Powershell only to create the agent